# Probability of a binary communication system

Tags: probability-distributions, binary

A binary communication system is used to send one of two messages: message A is a sequence of 0s with probability 2/3, message B is a sequence of 1s with probability 2/3,

The *i*th received bit is “correct" with probability 3/4, and is “incorrect" with probability 1/4. We assume that conditioned on any specific message sent, the received bits, denoted by Y1,Y2,… are independent. There are a few questions:

1) Find the probability that the first and second received bits are the same.

Because P(Y*i*=0)=7/12, P(Y*i*=1)=5/12. My answer is 7/12*7/12+5/12*5/12, but it is wrong, where did I make the mistake?

2)Given that Y1,…,Y5 were all equal to 0, what is the probability that Y6 is also zero?

Because all Y*i*s are independent, does it mean P(Y1=0)=P(Y6=0)?

3)Is Y2+Y3 independent of Y1? Is Y2−Y3 independent of Y1?

I can't figure out the relationship between them. Sometime, I think I misunderstand the meaning of independence.

4) Find the mean of K, where K=min{*i*:Y*i*=1} is the index of the first bit that is 1.

E=1/*p*=12/5, wrong answer again, really stuck here.:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many parts to cover in a single post but here is part 1:

1) Let the probability of message A be $p_A$ and message B be $p_B=1-p_A$, and the probability of reading a bit correctly be $p_c$ and incorrectly $p_i=1-p_c$. Then the probability of the first two bits reading the same is:
$$\begin{aligned}
p({\text{same)}}&=p_A(p_cp_c+p_ip_i)+p_B(p_cp_c+p_ip_i)\\ &=(2/3)\left[(3/4)^2+((1/4)^2 \right]+(1/3)\left[(3/4)^2+(1/4)^2 \right]\\ &=(3/4)^2+(1/4)^2=5/8=0.625
\end{aligned}$$

Hint for part 2:
Use Bayes theorem to compute the posterior probability of a message being A given that the first five bits are read all zero (and so also one minus this is the posterior probability that the message is B). Then use this to compute the probability that the sixth bit will be read as a zero.

Hint for part 3:
Independence of Z=Y2+Y3 and Y1 means that the joint pmf of Z and Y1 is equal to the product of the pmf of Z and the pmf of Y1. I used to think that you did not need to work this out explicitly it should be obviously true or false, but its not.

Hint for part 4:
Given that the message is A the probability that the $k$th first 1 is $p(K=k|A)=p_c^{k-1}p_i$, and similarly if the message is B we have $p(K=k|B)=p_i^{k-1}p_c$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just figured out the massage is a sequence of 0s or 1s, not arbitrary pick from {0, 1}. This misunderstanding leaded to the misinterpretation of independence.

Comment: For part3, I have worked out all pmfs and joint pmfs, but you said it is so obvious to tell true or false. Could you tell me how to intuitively solve this problem?

Comment: From my understanding, the value of Y1 will give the information of the message being sending, thereby affect the value of Y2 and Y3. Say, if Y1 is 0, it means the sending message has bigger probability to be a sequence of 0s, so Y2 and Y3 have bigger possibility to be 0s.

Comment: From pmfs calculation, Y2+Y3 is not independent of Y1, but Y2-Y3 is independent of Y1. Mathematically, the answer is right.  Intuitively, I have the same feeling as you.

Comment: You are right, obviously my intuition is wrong, just shows it is always worth actually doing the math.

Comment: In other words we have geometric R.V. given `A` or `B`. So we have to use law of total expectation: `E(X) = E(X|A) * P(A) + E(X|B) * P(B)`.